# Get selector parent id in jQuery click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the parent id of the element that was click, so in this case either `#logo200_60_form` or `#logo400_120_form`. I can then use that id in the rest of the code.

I tried `$(this).parent()` but that gives me the immediate parent and I would need to go up a couple of levels. As the id is in 
the click handler is there a way of determining which parent caused the click.

**JS :**

```
$('#logo200_60_form a.fileinput-exists, #logo400_120_form a.fileinput- exists').on('click', function() {
    $('form').get(0).reset();
    $('#logo200_60').trigger('change');
    $('#logo200_60_thumb').attr('src', 'http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image');
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<form action="#" role="form" id="logo200_60_form">
  <p>Please upload 200x60 png logo image</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
      <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 60px;">
        <img id="logo200_60_thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div id="logo200_60_preview" class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 60px;"></div>
      <div>
        <span class="btn default btn-file">
                                            <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
        <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
        <input type="file" name="..." id="logo200_60">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>

<form action="#" role="form" id="logo400_120_form">
  <p>Please upload 400x120 png logo image</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
      <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;">
        <img id="logo400_120_thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div id="preview" class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 120px;"></div>
      <div>
        <span class="btn default btn-file">
                                            <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
        <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
        <input type="file" name="..." id="logo400_120">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) <strike>with [attribute-value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).</strike>

```
$(this) // The element that is clicked
    .closest('form') // First <form> ancestor
    .attr('id') // Get the value of `id` attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried $(this).parent() but that gives me the immediate parent and I would need to go up a couple of levels.

You could use **[.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** instead, *Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector* :

```
$(this).parents('form').attr('id');
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#logo200_60_form a.fileinput-exists, #logo400_120_form a.fileinput-exists').on('click', function() {
 alert($(this).parents('form').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" role="form" id="logo200_60_form">
  <p> Please upload 200x60 png logo image</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
      <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 60px;">
        <img id="logo200_60_thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" /> </div>
      <div id="logo200_60_preview" class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 60px;"> </div>
      <div>
        <span class="btn default btn-file">
          <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
          <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
          <input type="file" name="..."    id="logo200_60"
                 > </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>      

<form action="#" role="form" id="logo400_120_form" >
  <p> Please upload 400x120 png logo image</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
      <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;">
        <img id="logo400_120_thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" /> </div>
      <div id="preview" class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 120px;"> </div>
      <div>
        <span class="btn default btn-file">
          <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
          <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
          <input type="file" name="..."  id="logo400_120"
                 > </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```